# Start-WebAppPool for Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, iis, web-applications, scripting

I'm experiencing a problem: I need a command to use on two different shells that gives me the chance to restart a web pool appliction, but only one of these shells is 4.0 (and has the command Start-WebAppPool) and the other one has Ps 4.0...
What I'm supposed to do?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you run Import-Module Webadministration ?

Comment: This was not possible due the version of Powershell. It was too old. Anyway, I'm posting the solution I found... Thanks for you help avvi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works surely from Powershell 2.0 and above.
I called it inside of a script like that:

```
$args = @()
$args += "stop"
$args += "apppool"
$args += "/apppool.name:PoolNameHere"
$cmd = "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"
```

Invoke-Expression "$cmd $args" #PoolNameHere stopped.

Dually, for restarting:

```
$args = @()
$args += "start"
$args += "apppool"
$args += "/apppool.name:PoolNameHere"
$cmd = "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"

Invoke-Expression "$cmd $args" #PoolNameHere started.
```

Hope this helps somebody!